# What data does WhatsApp see and use when you allow it to access contacts on iPhone

Tags: iphone, privacy

On iOS, what data does WhatsApp have access to if I allow it to see my contacts?

I expect names and numbers.

But does it also get access to addresses, Notes, etc? Does it use them in any way?

Comment: Assume it collects everything.

Comment: I agree with Allan. I personally don't use WhatsApp and noticed people complaining about WhatsApp not asking for permission to access contacts so you have to do it yourself in Settings, but [Control access to information in apps on iPhone - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iph251e92810/ios) says that you should "receive a request with an explanation" (obviously of what the app wants to access) the first time the app wants to access the info. So you could have gotten something telling you what they are looking for in the contacts data (didn't find answer online).